# Invoking function, closure

Tags: javascript

I experimented with closure and ran this code:

```js
var addTo = function (passed) {
 var add = function(inner){
  return passed + inner;
 };
 return add;
 }
var x = addTo(2);
console.log(x(4));
```

I don't understand why  this code only work when we use var x in console.log and don't with console.log(addTo(4)); Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `addTo` returns a function so if you console log `addTo(4)` you're going to be logging a function that needs to be invoked, itself, before you get something meaningful out of it.

Comment: Because then it becomes: `console.log(addTo(2)(4));`

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the code. If we start with

```
var addTo = function (passed) {
 var add = function(inner){
  return passed + inner;
 };
 return add;
}
var x = addTo(2);
console.log(x(4));
```

then let's ignore scope and unpack it:

```
function actualAdd(passed, inner){
 return passed + inner;
};

function addTo(passed) {
 return function(x) { return actualAdd(passed, x);
}

var addSomethingTo2 = addTo(2);

// This is a handle for the actualAdd() function,
// in which "passed" is always the value 2.
console.log(addSomethingTo2); 

var thisIsSix = addSomethingTo2(4);

// By calling addSomethingTo2(4) we run the calculation
// 2 + 4 and return the result of that: 6
console.log(thisIsSix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `addTo` function returns another function, the function `add`.

When you do `x = addTo(2)`, the value of `x` is now the function `add`, which has access to the value `2` you passed to `addTo`.

When you do `console.log(x(4))` after you have done `x = addTo(2)`, that is equal to doing `console.log(addTo(2)(4))` which means:

- Invoke `addTo` with `2` as an argument
- `addTo` returns `add` which has access to the passed `2` due to the closure
- Invoke the function returned by `addTo` (the function `add`) with an argument of `4`
- Return the sum of `passed` and `inner`

To sum up, it would not work with `console.log(addTo(4))` because the value returned by `addTo` is another function, so `console.log` will simply print something like `Function`